# How to set Play's "current directory" to the app's homedir?

Tags: ubuntu, playframework

I'm trying to use this [Ubuntu Upstart script](https://gist.github.com/2029862) to set up Play to run as a service, and, am having problems with log4j. The script essentially does:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --exec /home/ubuntu/programs/play/current/play 
                  --chuid ubuntu:ubuntu -- start /home/ubuntu/myapp/src/ --%id
```

Play starts up ok, but it then fails to create the log4j file. I believe `start-stop-daemon` does not correctly sets the folder for log4j. Log4j is configured to create a log file at relative path `logs/play.log`, which translates to `/home/ubuntu/myapp/logs/play.log`. The folder `/home/ubuntu/myapp/logs/` does exist, but I get this error when Play starts:

> log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs/play.log (No such file or
>   directory)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:212)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:136)
>           at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)

Meaning that the "current directory" for Play is not the play home dir, but rather something else. Now, I can change it by providing an absolute log4j path, but it seems like a hack, and I wonder if other components that rely on the Play current folder will exhibit similar problems.

So, how I can ensure Play's current directory is identical to the app's homedir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was adding `--chdir $HOME` to the `start-stop-daemon` line. Quite trivial to be frank.

Comment: How it can be adapted for RedHat? There is no start-stop-daemon for that OS. Thanks.

Comment: @Meglio - I'm not sure. Try asking a new question about this.